# Find bpy function in source code

Tags: python

What is the best way to locate a function from the `bpy` module in Blender's source code?  I've downloaded the [source code](http://www.blender.org/download/) and I'm aware you can also browse through it [online](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/).

As an example, I would like to inspect `bpy.ops.render.render()`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Get the idname like:

```
bpy.ops.render.render.idname()
# 'RENDER_OT_render'
```

(or simply take `render.render` and replace the `.` by `_OT_`)

Search that operator in the source code, and find it here:

```
blender\source\blender\editors\render\render_internal.c
```

```
/* contextual render, using current scene, view3d? */
void RENDER_OT_render(wmOperatorType *ot)
{
    PropertyRNA *prop;

    /* identifiers */
    ot->name = "Render";
    ot->description = "Render active scene";
    ot->idname = "RENDER_OT_render";

    /* api callbacks */
    ot->invoke = screen_render_invoke;
    ot->modal = screen_render_modal;
    ot->cancel = screen_render_cancel;
    ot->exec = screen_render_exec;
```

You'll likely wanna look for the exec function code (`screen_render_exec`) and see what it does.

Comment: How can I find classes that have no `idname()` like `bpy.types.Scene` in the code?

Comment: I would search the folder structure and by filename for those. Regarding the Scene type, check `blenkernel`, `makesrna` and `makesdna`: https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/blenkernel/BKE_scene.h / https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/makesdna/DNA_scene_types.h / https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/makesrna/intern/rna_scene.c / https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/makesrna/intern/rna_scene_api.c

Comment: Thanks, but I am searching for the python definition of the normal `bpy.types.Scene()` [class](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Scene.html)

Comment: To my knowledge, it is only defined in the C code in `rna_scene.c`. Are you looking for the glue code that exposes the properties and methods to Python?

Comment: Yes, that's what I am looking for

Comment: I assume this is the most relevant part: `intern/bpy.c:285` https://goo.gl/RUkrYc (shortened URL because SO breaks Phabricator deep links). The Scene type is not exposed explicitly anywhere as far as I can tell, because it is part of the DNA/RNA system and all types are exposed my generic code to make the properties and functions defined in the C code available in the bpy python interface. If you need more information, I suggest to contact the Blender developers via IRC.

Answer (score 1):

Python offers a module for live [inspection](http://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#retrieving-source-code).  If the function is a python function located in a .py file, you can use these functions.

For example,

```
import bpy
import inspect

#get sourcefile of a panel
inspect.getfile(bpy.types.VIEW3D_PT_transform_orientations)
#...blender-2.69-windows64\blender-2.69-windows64\2.69\scripts\startup\bl_ui\space_view3d.py

bpy.data.texts.new('source').write(
    inspect.getsource(bpy.types.VIEW3D_PT_transform_orientations)
    )
```

(for the difference between `.getfile` and `.getsourcefile` see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761337/inspect-getfile-vs-inspect-getsourcefile) on stackoverflow)

Comment: Why does `inspect.getfile(bpy.ops.render.render)` not work?  I get a `TypeError` error saying it `is not a module, class, method, function, traceback, frame, or code object`.

Comment: pink vertex's example shows `inspect.getfile()` using a `bpy.types` class. So the proper call for an operator is `inspect.getfile(getattr(bpy.types, bpy.ops.render.render.idname()))`, which will raise a **TypeError**: <RNA_Types object at 0x0000000003A875A0> **is a built-in class**. You need search it in the C code (see my answer where to find it).