# Is it possible to open a script which contains a function which a button executes?

Tags: python

I'm trying to find the scripts which execute blender functions like 
**bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add()**,
but I can't find those scripts. If anyone knows how to do this, please reply.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/47678/2843

Answer (score 2):

Most of Blender's core operations are not python scripts, but rather compiled C++ code. If you want to see how these are written, you can download and investigate [Blender's source code](http://archive.blender.org/download/source-code/index.html).

Most addons are a different matter. They're almost all in Python, and you can usually find these in the `Scripts/Addons` folder under blender's installation directory (for instance in my Win7 installation: `C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.76\scripts\addons`).

Comment: thanks for the link.if u know where i can find the code for basic edit mode functions like extrude, creating basic mesh like cube, bevel ,etc.
And ill also be searching for them.
Thanks again

Comment: [this question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6880/935) should help you find them.

Answer (score 0):

These are no Scripts in all cases but you can use the [Blender Python API](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/) which is pretty well documented, e.g. for your asked [bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.ops.mesh.html#bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add). They usually invoke [direct C functions](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/editors/mesh/editmesh_add.c$134) as well, just the API calls can be done in Python - which is quite handy for scripting. All these available Operators are later [appended](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/editors/mesh/mesh_ops.c$71) to the Blender Python object that you can access via `bpy.` for scripting.

There is a great built-in history of most of your executed commands hidden in the Info View (where your File menu is located) which you can show by resizing your Info View to somewhat bigger:

[image: Resize Info View]

Answer (score -1):

Open a *Text Editor* View and open one of the Python *Template* files:

[image: Python Templates]

Comment: When this answer is "Not useful" as the DV states: Then what exactly is not useful with it? It acutally shows where you can find *some* of the useful Python codes in Blender.