# Making Proxy on a Linked Rig via the API

Tags: python, armature, linked-data

Using the blender API, I am trying to "Make Proxy" on a linked rig.

My first approach was to identify the linked objects through `bpy.data.groups.objects` and then use the `bpy.ops.object.proxy_make()` operator to make proxies.

However, this would make proxies for all linked objects (rigs, meshes etc.), when my objective is to do it only to the rigs.

Is there a way to identify the right objects to proxy? Alternatively, is there a better method to do the whole exercise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The make proxy operator works only on the active object (it has to be visible). You set the active object like this:

```
import bpy
objects = bpy.context.scene.objects
objects.active = objects["Name"]
```

If you don't know the name you can list all objects in the scene with dupli group:

```
ob_list = [ob for ob in objects if ob.dupli_group]
```

You can specify what object inside the group to make the proxy of like this:

```
bpy.ops.object.proxy_make(object="Name_Of_Object_Inside_Linked_Group")
```

If you don't know the name, you can list all the armatures inside the active object's dupli group:

```
armatures = [ob for ob in objects.active.dupli_group.objects if ob.type == 'ARMATURE']
```

The proxy object then becomes the active object. You can rename the proxy easily (otherwise it will carry the name of the linked group object):

```
objects.active.name = "Name_Of_Object_Inside_Linked_Group_PROXY"
```

To complete this you also get the linked group object from a proxy object like this (if you need to know what the proxy is influencing and if the object is a proxy at all):

```
group_ob = proxy_ob.proxy_group
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. Learned some new things. Very helpful

Comment: when executing `bpy.ops.object.proxy_make(object="Name_Of_Object_Inside_Linked_Group")` from script I got the famous `bpy.ops.object.proxy_make.poll() failed, context is incorrect`. I tried some context override but I failed. is there a way to make the override working or can we make proxy without ops at all ?

Comment: @Pullup search the operator in source code like this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6880/find-bpy-function-in-source-code and find it's poll() method. See what members of bpy.context it checks. Override all the context members like so: https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.ops.html#overriding-context. If there is still problem you will have to ask that as a question and show the code for debugging as it won't be probably trivial.