# Operator : bpy.ops.object.proxy_make()

Tags: python, scripting, rigging

I've got some trouble with `bpy.ops.object.proxy_make()`.

To resume:

- my script import a character who has a rig.
- this character is imported as a link then I make it a proxy of the armature.

My script run fine on blender scripting area, run fine with batch but if i execute-it from panel or menu it stuck on `bpy.ops.object.proxy_make()`.

This script is placed on a folder, call from init.py - this folder is on blender addons folder.

`__init__.py` call-it

```py
from . import myScript

    class simpleClass(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "myPanel.simple_class"
    bl_label = "my simple script"
    bl_description = "simple script"

    def execute(self, context):
        myScript.run()
        return {'FINISHED'}

...register stuff
```

`myScript.py` *i've juste pasted essential*

```py
scene = bpy.context.scene
with bpy.data.libraries.load(currentPath, link=True) as (data_from, data_to):
            data_to.collections = data_from.collections

        for new_coll in data_to.collections:
            if new_coll.name.endswith('.anim'):
                instance = bpy.data.objects.new(new_coll.name, None)
                instance.instance_type = 'COLLECTION'
                instance.instance_collection = new_coll
                scene.collection.objects.link(instance)
                armature = new_coll.name.split("_")[0] + "_armature"
                ob = scene.objects[new_coll.name]
                ob.select_set(True)
                bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = ob
                bpy.ops.object.proxy_make(object=armature)
```

terminal :

```
location: <unknown location>:-1
Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.82\2.82\scripts\addons\myFolder\__init__.py", line 132, in execute
    bpy.ops.object.proxy_make(object=armature)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.82\2.82\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 201, in __call__
    ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.object.proxy_make.poll() failed, context is incorrect

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

**Tested on centOS7 & Win10, blender 2.82**

I turn around long time before posting here...
i've found this thread & more precisely answser of @pullup

[Making Proxy on a Linked Rig via the API](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73228/making-proxy-on-a-linked-rig-via-the-api#comment149266_73245)

But i don't know how to override this. and i don't know if the right way ?

Thanks for reading,